# Passing table data with post variables

Tags: php

Basically I have a table with a bunch of numbers coming from a database with columns for totals/subtotals. I do not intend to add any of the totals to the database, but I need to pass the total numbers from one page to the next. I can't seem to properly pass them as post variables using PHP... I'm wondering if this is a bad tactic firstly, secondly what should I do instead?

And if this is possible, how would I go about doing it? I haven't been able to derive the text between the < td >'s from using $_POST['tdname'].

Example code:

```
<form method="POST" action="newcivilreport2.php">

            <div style="width:800px;text-align:left;margin:0 auto;padding-bottom:5px;">A. PENDING BALANCE</div>
            <table border="1" style="width:800px;" ID="tableA">
            <th style="width:40%;"></th>
            <th style="width:15%;">Civil</th>
            <th style="width:15%;">Asbestos</th>
            <th style="width:15%;">Domestic</th>
            <th style="width:15%;">Total</th>
            <tr>
            <td>1. Pending Balance from Previous Month</td>
            <td id="PendingCivil" name="PendingCivil">66</td>
            <td id="PendingAsbestos">0</td>
            <td id="PendingDomestic">0</td>
            <td id="PendingTotal">0</td>
            </tr>
            </table> 
<input type="submit" value="Save and Continue -->"></form></div>
```

newcivilreport2.php:

```
<?php
    $_POST['PendingCivil'];
?>
```

Comment: It should be possible to pass the data as post variables. Could you post some of your code so that we can try and figure out what you are doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<td>` tag of a table does not provide values for a form.

Use a hidden field for your post:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type.asp

```
...
<td>1. Pending Balance from Previous Month</td>
<td id="PendingCivil">66<input type="hidden" name="PendingCivil" value="66"></td>
...
```

Also, is it inside of a form?

Comment: The problem with this is that the value is set as 66, whereas the value will change from 66 according to whatever the calculation is.

Comment: (I had a typo, so this was before his thanks) Then use some javascript to update the value after calculation. [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) makes like easier!

Answer (score 7):

POST will only send inputs like `<input type='text|file|hidden|ect' />`. Perhaps you would like to use AJAX. For example:

```
<table id="tData">
     <tbody>
         <tr>
             <td class='dataVal1'>100</td>
      ...

$(document).ready(function() {
    var toServer = {};
    var data = $('#tData tbody tr td').each(function(key, value) {
        toServer[$(this).attr('id')] = $(this).text();
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: 'page.php',
        data: toServer,
        type: 'POST'
    })
});
```