# Passing Data Collection via PHP URL

Tags: php, laravel, url, collections

suppose I have `$data`, which is a collection of entire data of a table, is it possible to pass this collection type data in parameters via URL from view to controller?

I'm using Laravel. All the solutions I've been searching only for array type data. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

You can. First install the package `guzzlehttp/guzzle`. then try this way:

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

$client = new Client();
$sampleData = ['name' => 'billy', 'email' => 'billy@example.com']; // your collection
$url = 'http://api.example.com/bla-bla'; // your url

$res = $client->request('POST', "{$url}",['form_params' => $sampleData]);
$data = json_decode(json_encode($res->getBody()->getContents()),true);
return $data;
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't this passing from controller to view? How to do it vice versa? I mean, variable data in view called to controller via URL @Abdullah

Comment: This should be in your controller. There is nothing related to view. $data means the collection you want to send. URL means the enpoint you want to send data. I updated my code please check.

Answer (score 0):

Make a post request from your view to the required URL.

Example:
Adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6933014/passing-table-data-with-post-variables)

```
<table id="tData">
     <tbody>
         <tr>
             <td class='dataVal1'>100</td>
      ...

$(document).ready(function() {
    var toServer = {};
    var data = $('#tData tbody tr td').each(function(key, value) {
        toServer[$(this).attr('id')] = $(this).text();
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: '/test/',
        data: {
                "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
                "table_data": toServer,
              }
        type: 'POST'
    })
});
```

Now in your controller which handles the page, use the following

```
public function test(Request $request)
{
  dd($request);
}
```

Note: Make sure the URL which you mention in the ajax request can accept post request.

Comment: This above code POST the data from your table to co the controller via POST request. I don't think its a good idea to pass the data via URL parameters to the controller, however, please post your code sample if you want an example for that.